# what's wrong with this query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT SET FIXEDCOST = 
   (Select PRICE from PRODUCTPROGRAM 
    where productID = PRODUCTID) * .6 
WHERE FAMILY = 'Services'
```

I need to update the `PRODUCT` table's `FIXEDCOST` field with 60% of the value of Price in the `PRODUCTPROGRAM` table.

The tables are related by `productID`.

The error says that more than one is returned in the subquery. Any ideas as to how I could fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So what does Select PRICE from PRODUCTPROGRAM where productID = PRODUCTID return? Given the name of the table, I would not be suprised to find that productId was not unique column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tamer, you are getting too many results in the "select price from proudctprogram" you need narrow it down or do something like this:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT A, PRODUCTPROGRAM B   
SET A.FIXEDCOST = B.PRICE * .6 
WHERE A.productID = B.PRODUCTID AND FAMILY ='Services'
```

Try that and let me know.
Marcelo

Answer (score 1):

While i'm not sure the syntax is 100% you may want to first try to reference which table each productId is set to i.e. PRODUCT.productid  and PRODUCTPROGRAM.PRODUCTID.

Answer (score 1):

The nested query will return all records from the PRODUCTPROGRAM table, as all records have a PRODUCTID value that is equal to itself.

You have to specify that you want to compare it to the value in the PRODUCT table:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET FIXEDCOST =
  (Select PRICE from PRODUCTPROGRAM 
  where productID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID) * .6 
WHERE FAMILY = 'Services'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE PRODUCT p
    JOIN PRODUCTPROGRAM pp ON pp.productID = p.productID
SET p.FIXEDCOST = pp.PRICE *.6
WHERE p.FAMILY = 'Services'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE PRODUCT SET FIXEDCOST = 
   (Select TOP 1 PRICE from PRODUCTPROGRAM 
    where productID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID) * .6 
WHERE FAMILY = 'Services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query must be returning more than one value.

```
Select PRICE from PRODUCTPROGRAM 
where productID = PRODUCTID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting the subquery or use the unique key in the where clause:

```
    UPDATE PRODUCT SET FIXEDCOST = 
   (Select PRICE from PRODUCTPROGRAM 
    where productID = PRODUCTID LIMIT 1) * .6 
WHERE FAMILY = 'Services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use table aliases to avoid ambiguity? Like UPDATE PRODUCT P SET FIXEDCOST = (SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCTPROGRAM PP WHERE P.PRODUCTID = PP.PRODUCTID) ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the where-statement is wrong. You mean, probably:

```
where productID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
```